# Loadstring Equivalent in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a class that I have declared and created various objects of.  For example:

```
class contact { 
    //whatnot
};
//later:
contact c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 // and so on
```

I then have a function that returns a number (int x), which corresponds to the number alongside each variable.  Is there a way for me to convert this number into code so that I can reference that specific instance of the class, similar to Lua's *loadstring()* function?  Is there a better way to go about this?  Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea about the relationship between the number and instance. If i get your mean, you want to find the correct object correspoing to the declaration sequence number, but in fact there is no order when you define the five objects above which may be saved in discontinuity memory. so it's impossible get the object from a number. but you can declare an array which will save your object one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a collection of variables of same type, you could use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in C++:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<contract> c(1000);
//c[0]  refers to c1
//c[1]  refers to c2
//c[2]  refers to c3
//c[3]  refers to c4
//c[4]  refers to c5
// and so on
```

Comment: Thank you, and I feel quite silly that I didn't think of that prior to asking.  However, the second part of this function requires the number to refer to various textlabels, named s1, s2, s3, s4 etc.  However, attempting to put these objects in an array or vector results in an error, as managed classes cannot be stored in arrays or vectors.  There are only ten of them, so I can always use if/else if statements to get the correct label, but I was hoping to find a way to directly link between the class and the label without a conditional.

Comment: `However, attempting to put these objects in an array or vector results in an error`, can you show some more code relative to this?

Comment: Thank you for asking; in the process of inspecting the error, I realized I had left out a ^.  Everything is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want individual variables - you want an array:

```
contact c[42];  // choose boundary to taste.
```

Now you can write `c[x]`.